# Update cursor into list of pairs : "TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row"

Tags: python-2.7, list, arcpy

I'm new in programming and struggling with a problem.

I have a pairs list and I want to update the field of a table with the second value of these pairs to have this result:

```
 RowID  Field
 1       b
 2       d
```

This my code:

```
pairs = [('a', 'b') , ('c', 'd')]

for row in pairs:
   first = row[0]
   second = row[1]
   with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(myTable, "Field") as cursor1:
      for row2 in cursor1:
      row2 = second
      cursor1.updateRow(row2)
```

But I get the following message error:

> cursor1.updateRow(row2)
>       TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you only using the second pair value?  What is the purpose of the first value in each pair?  Does the number of rows match the number of value pairs in your list?

Comment: For ArcPy I think you are better researching/asking at the [GIS.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: The first values of the pairs were used in a previous step of my code: they are not useful for this one.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange that I will use for the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be getting this error because you're trying to set the value for an entire row, rather than the single field.  Your row is a list of all fields - `[Field]` - and you need to write to a specific field - `Field` - so need to reference that value in the row list.

```
row2[0] = second
```

That said, I think you'll always get the same value `d` because you're only referencing the second value from the second pair.

Step through your list once inside the cursor.  If you have more rows in your table than values in the list it'll print the message `not enough values in list`.

```
pairs = [('a', 'b') , ('c', 'd')]
i = 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(myTable, "Field") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if not i > len(pairs):
            row = pairs[i][1]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            print "not enough values in list"
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you Midivalo, it worked with the two corrections (indexing row and steping through the list)!